# How set swagger client claims with identityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I'm protecting a .NET Core Web API with an access token issued by an IDS4.

It works and I added some claims in the client configuration, as follows:

```
// ... other code
new Client
{
    ClientId = "apiclient",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets = {
        new Secret("mysupersecret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = { 
        "joinot", 
        JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    },
    Claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim("role", "WonderWoman"), new Claim("VatId", "123abc") },
},
// ... other code
```

These are the claims that I see in the webapi.

I found what I added with the prefix "client_".

[image]

For testing purposes I'm using swagger and I have this config for it:

```
new Client {
    ClientId = "swagger_api_client",
    ClientName = "Swagger API Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:57303/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"},
    AllowedScopes = { 
        "joinot", 
        JwtClaimTypes.Role, 
    },
    Claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim("role", "ManOfSteel"), new Claim("VatId", "abc123") },
    RequireConsent = false
},
```

This means that I have to authenticate with an interactive user and than I can call the webapi.

When I do it, the claims I found in the webapi are not as I expected.

"client_role" and "client_VatId" are not in the list.

[image]

***How can I insert the claims for both the console and the swagger client?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `AlwaysSendClientClaims` to true :

```
Claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim("role", "WonderWoman"), new Claim("VatId", "123abc") },
AlwaysSendClientClaims =true,
```

If set, the client claims will be sent for every flow. If not, only for client credentials flow (default is false) . So your console application which use client credential flow would work even not set that property.

Reference document : http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html